# Define a complex model

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I have the following `user` object (`json`):

```
{
    "_id": "my-id",
    "org": 666,
    "type": "user",
    "properties": {
        "first_name": "Firstname",
        "surname1": "Surname1",
        "surname2": "Surname2",
        "allowed_apps": [ "one-app", "another-app" ],
        "default_app": "one-app",
        "email": "email@address.com"
    },
    "outputs": {
        "extension": "extension-id"
    }
}
```

This is a single model, with a complex structure. It is not a "multi-model structure". Therefore, I want to define this using `DS.Model.extend`, but I do *not* want to use `belongsTo` relationships for neither `properties` nor `outputs`, since they do not refer to *other* models: these fields are just complex data, direct part of my `user` object. That is, we do not have any `properties` model, nor any `outputs` model. These are just parts of the `user` model, and as such are stored in the database (couchdb in our case).

Can this be done in ember?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Lamentably this kind of structure is not possible using `ember-data` models.
Every value of a model that is not a primitive one such as `string`, `number`, `boolean` & `date` can't be defined as a model property without designing it with `belongsTo` or `hasMany`. Furthermore this site [jsonapi.org](http://jsonapi.org/) which is still a WIP describes the direction `ember-data` is going with it's implementation.

So the point is here if you want/need to use `ember-data` models (DS.Model) your server should obey the JSON format `ember-data` expects, otherwise you have always the possibility (since ember-data is backend agnostic) to not use `ember-data` models definition at all, this way your models can be structured the way you want, but then you are out of being helped from the conventional work `ember-data` adapter and serializer does for you and you have to write your own adapter/s which then deals with all the peculiarities your JSON's have and load them finally into your store.

If you absolutely need a custom data structure to be exchanged with your backend, you can register a custom transform like for example:

```
App.Adapter.registerTransform('mega', {
  deserialize: function(serialized) {
    //do your custom deserialization
  },
  serialize: function(deserialized) {
    //do your custom serialization
  }
});
```

and then use it like:

```
App.MyModel = DS.Model.extend({
  megaValue: DS.attr('mega');
});
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks! I will investigate the custom transform option.

Comment: @intuitivepixel Could you give an example of what custom serialization/deserialization might look like?